# Jenkins : build project using different remote

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I want to build a maven project using Jenkins,

I have two remotes : origin and myfork.

In the build configuration, exactly in the field "Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')" I want to specify  "myfork" as the remote to use in the build

[image: ![enter image description here]

But this is not working and it gives me this error :

> git.exe rev-parse "origin/myfork/testBranch^{commit}" # timeout=10
>   ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
>   Finished: FAILURE

clearly he is trying to pull from "origin/myfork/testBranch^{commit}" however it should be "myfork/testBranch^{commit}"

how may I correct this ?

Answer (score 0):

The response is simple : We add the word remotes before the branch name as this : remotes/myfork/testBranch